# Can spring security re-try an authentication attempt with the same credentials in the same request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot security, implementing `UserDetailsService` and having `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configure `HttpSecurity` to use `.antMatchers(pattern).authenticated()`.

If I want to cache the `UserDetails` then there is a problem that when the details change, the cache is stale. It is not easy to signal to the cache that the details have changed. A nice solution would be to let the user log in with new credentials, and when that fails because they are using the new password, **within the same HTTP request** invalidate the cache and try again with the same credentials.

Is this possible?

Comment: why not invalidating the cache when the user changes his credentials?

Comment: External services change credentials. These cannot be modified.